# Issue in ckeditor5

Tags: ckeditor5

i have install ckeditor5 on my website(after online builder) and it work perfectly but the only issue that if in introduce a code it look perfectly in editor but after submit it is shown as plain text
[image: the code in editor]

[image: the code in topic after submit]

How can i resolve this issue

ckeditor code-block issue after submit